# Replace img src from elements attribute

Tags: jquery, toggle, image, src

If I have this html on my page

```
<img src="samesrc" class="commentimg" name="differentimg1"/>
```

How onclick can I toggle the `src=` of `<img>` with the `name=` attribute, so when I click the `<img>` the src becomes *differentimg1*, and another class is applied

```
<img src="differentimg1" class="commentimg commentimgresize" name="differentimg1"/>
```

and then when clicked again the html source is returned to original ie

```
<img src="samesrc" class="commentimg" name="differentimg1"/>
```

This should be applied to all images but the src when toggled should correspond the element `name=` value.

**I HAVE TRIED** http://jsfiddle.net/yusaf/zy5j8/25/

```
$('.imgreplace').each(function(){
$('.imgreplace').click(function(){
    var replacesrc = $(".commentimg").attr("name");
    $('.commentimg').attr("src", "+replacesrc+");
    $('.commentimg').toggleClass('commentimgresize')
})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
$('.commentimg').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('src');
    var b = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).attr('src',b).attr('name', a);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/zy5j8/26/

**Explanation:** `Onclick` grab the `src` and `name` attributes, reverse them.

Comment: this is brilliant, just missed one thing but I got that, http://jsfiddle.net/yusaf/zy5j8/31/ , thankyou very much.

Comment: @Yusaf - This is indeed a better answer than mine - it overwrites the name attribute, but that doesn't really even matter.  Name doesn't do anything for an img, and is in fact **deprecated** for this tag (and others).  In the future, if you need a placeholder attribute, you can use an html5 data attribute - data-swapsrc='...' It's cross-browser safe too

Answer (score 2):

So on click, make src = name, unless they are equal, in which case set src back to what it was originally.  The trick will be remembering what the original src was; the data function—which lets you store arbitrary data on an element by key—can help you do this.

```
$(".imgreplace").click(function() {
    if (this.attr("src") !== this.attr("name")) {
       this.data("oldsrc", this.attr("src"));
       this.attr("src", this.attr("name"));
    } else
       this.attr("src", this.data("oldsrc"));
    this.toggleClass('commentimgresize');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.commentimg').click(function(){
    var replacesrc = $(this).attr("name");
    $(this).attr("src", replacesrc).toggleClass('commentimgresize');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant add a variable like that, try :

```
var replacesrc = $(".commentimg").attr("name");
$('.commentimg').attr("src", replacesrc);
```

Also, using an url as a name probably is'nt the best of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Using `name` for a URL is wrong (Google, for one, will get confused).

Instead, try using a `data-` attribute, like this:

```
<img
  src="url1" 
  class="commentimg"
  data-src2="url2"/>

$('.commentimg').click(function(){
    var temp_src = $(this).attr('data-src2');
    $(this)
        .attr('data-src2', $(this).attr('src'))
        .attr('src', temp_src)
        .toggleClass('commentimgresize');
});
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zy5j8/30/).